# Delete a single document from nested document array by its id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this model for a user, the user can also be a driver and the driver have an array of cars. I want to delete a specific car from all the cars of drivers, but my query deletes all the cars.

This is the schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
      },

  driverData: {
    ExperienceLevel: {
      type: String,
    },

    rides: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "ride.model",
      },
    ],

    cars: [
      {
        id: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        },

        licensePlateNumber: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Code I am using to pull a car by id.

```
user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { driverData: { cars: { $pull: { id: carId } } } }
    );
```

Only a single car object and a single car id is left after making this query, all other data is removed. How to only remove only a single car.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. Try this:

`user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( { _id: userId }, { $pull: { driverData: { cars: { $elemMatch: { id: carId } } } } );`

Comment: It shows this error, because I think driverData is not array.

{
    "error": "Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"
}

Comment: Using this removes all the cars

user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { driverData: { $pull: { cars: { $elemMatch: { id: carId } } } } }
    );

Comment: Try this: `user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( { _id: userId }, { driverData: { $pull: { cars: { $elemMatch: { id: carId } } } } } );`

Comment: Already tried this, it is not working

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).